# Nginx 404s all static assets in Flask / Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

All my static assets are 404ing. I have no idea why, since my Nginx is correctly routing them and when I bash into the docker container I can see the assets are there.

Here's my nginx config:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream flask {
    server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    # the domain name it will serve for
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/app/myApp/static; # your project's static files - amend as required
        autoindex on;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  flask;
        include  uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a broken link from my template:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/main.css') }}">`

Which results in a 404 on this path, which looks to be correct:

> http://localhost:9090/static/dist/css/main.css

I'm not sure what other information you would need to diagnose this, everything else seems to be working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: The port number is different. 8080 vs 9090?

Comment: Are these commands working inside your docker container: `cd /usr/src/app/app/myApp/static` and `cat /usr/src/app/app/myApp/static/dist/css/main.css`?

Comment: @Fian Yep, those work.

Comment: @RichardSmith My docker-compose routes 9090:8080

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the `server_name _;`. Remove it or set `server_name localhost` or `server_name ~.`.